# Apple Removes Blockchain Bitcoin Wallet Apps from its App Stores

Tags: wallet, client, ios

That Apple removed last wallet from their app store.  Just wrong....  Guess more people will move to Android.

Apple Removes Blockchain Bitcoin Wallet Apps from its App Stores

http://www.coindesk.com/apple-removes-blockchain-bitcoin-wallet-from-app-stores/

**Will they add it back after seeing the pressure from worldwide bitcoin community?**

I love the response from BlockChain to Apple

http://blog.blockchain.info/2014/02/06/blockchain-response-to-apple/

Blockchain’s Response to Apple
Posted on February 6, 2014

```
“Here’s to the crazy ones. The misfits. The rebels. The troublemakers. The round pegs in  the square holes. The ones who see things differently. They’re not fond of rules. And they have no respect for the status quo. You can quote them, disagree with them, glorify or vilify them. About the only thing you can’t do is ignore them. Because they change things. They push the human race forward.” – Apple, Inc.

Perhaps Apple should have added a disclaimer: “As long as the ‘rebels’ don’t threaten our profit margin”. The rebels no longer run the show at Apple Inc; the beancounters are now firmly in charge.
```

http://blog.blockchain.info/2014/02/07/the-media-bitcoin-community-respond-to-apple/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has had plans to convert iPhones into a mobile payment centre for a long time. Since they have such a grand bulk of the market and deep-pockets, they think they can have force banks and vendors to accept it, and then earn a lot of money from profits due to being the middle man - mimmicking the wild success they had with iTunes (where they have much more leveraging power than the music firms themselves by controlling the market).

They won't accept any crypto-currency app into their official market as long as they still have that business plan. Only when such adventurous proposal is tried and fails or when the business deals go nowhere after too much time will they ever consider allowing them back.

Right now there are tons of stuff Android phones can do that can't be done with (unjailed and unpatched) iPhones. Yet people still buy any iStuff by the dozen - so Apple executives know deep within most people don't really care about choice. Unless/until the market starts caring, that will still be their position.